# Get String of M/d/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy Formatted As String of yyyyMMdd

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a string in either the format of `M/d/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` and I have been working to convert this string to another string of a different format of `yyyyMMdd`, and these are some techniques I've been testing just to get initial string formats, yet all are coming out as nulls in spark's sql:

```
SELECT 
  current_date() AS RightNow ---Returns today's date
  , date_format("8/15/2019","MM-dd-yyyy") AS FormatDate  ---Returns null
  , TO_DATE("8/15/2019") AS OtherFormat ---Returns null
  , CAST("8/15/2019" as date) Casted ---Returns null
  , CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('8/15/2019', 'yyyyMMdd') AS TIMESTAMP) TestFour ---Returns null
```

What's peculiar is that when I read other answers, I see some users saying that the output is dates, yet all there are returning null.  The input is a string and the output from sql must be a string.  T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read your post a little more carefully...

`to_date("8/15/2019","MM/dd/yyyy")` will convert your string to an actual date. The second argument is the input format of your data.

To convert that to your desired string format:

```
date_format(to_date("8/15/2019","MM/dd/yyyy"),"yyyyMMdd")
```

The second argument for date_format is your desired output format. The first argument must be an actual date.